# "Stood up from the dressing table chair" OR "Stood up from the dressing table"?

Tags: word-choice

Laura *stood up from the dressing table chair/stood up from the dressing table* with a gun in her right hand.

Which is understandable for you? Can I write it without the "chair"?

Comment: Yes. It works. Please see also [writers.se] This question is not about the English language but about writing. Good Luck.

Comment: This question is better asked on [writers.se]

Comment: I did not know about Writing Stack Exhange. I will consider using it on my next question. Thank you so much for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

It's understandable to me without the use of "chair!"

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have the privilege, use "comments" to post your comment.

Comment: To the question, "Which is understandable for you? Can I write it without the 'chair'?", my response is definitely an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set the scene, so that the reader knows that Laura is seated at her dressing table, then

> Laura stood up holding/brandishing a gun

is more dramatic than trying to set the scene and its action in one awkward sentence. We know that people use "a hand" to hold things, so there is no need to waffle the sentence. And unless it matters to the plot that Laura is right-handed, don't mention it.

Comment: I asked this question because I had to choose between "stood up from the dressing table chair", and "stood up from the dressing table". I read both variants, however I found the latter in older texts most of the time. I wanted to know whether the shorter form is still understandable for the majority of people. Your answer does not mention any of the variants in my question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: That is because I didn't think that either version works well, and so I tried make a more general helpful answer.

Comment: I would have appreciated if you have written this for the first time. Because analizing a scene that does not exist seemed a bit too general answer to me. I just wanted to write an interesting example sentence, to make people interested in my question about the two variants. Two answers per fifteen views looks pretty good to me. I will think about publish a book with Laura. :) :) :)